# Are pending desktop apps ever going to be accepted?

Tags: software-center

It says on the review status page of my app:

> "Thank you for submitting a gratis Free Software application through
>   MyApps. At this time we are unable to process this request, as we are
>   working on the implementation of a new app upload process.
>
> To get your software out to millions of Ubuntu users in the meantime,
>   you can either use a Personal Package Archive to distribute your app
>   for free, or you can define a price to charge for your app."

This whole thing seems to be sooo confusing right now. I have a PPA, but I want my app to be added to USC. It seems that there's now a beta version of the new process.

Is it only for mobile apps with Click packages? Should I delete my entry and resubmit it?

Comment: You should probably use the contact page at https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/ to get support for this issue from Canonical.

Comment: I can very well be wrong, as I have no knowledge about where and how the upload procedures are managed, but to me it seems rather a decision than a bug. The message screen is quite clear about that.